# Run Scrapy and Splash from Docker

Tags: docker, scrapy-splash

Newbie question: I have splash running in a docker container and scrapy running on my local development machine.  I now need to promote this to an AWS environment via docker containers, but I can't figure out how to connect the scrapy and splash containers?

I'm assuming that I need to create a docker stack, but that's as far as I've got :o(

Answer (score 0):

It was really quite straightforward in the end.

```
docker network create crawler-network

docker run --network=crawler-network --name=splash --hostname=splash --memory=6GB --restart unless-stopped -d -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --max-timeout 600 --slots 10

docker run --network=crawler-network --name=crawler --hostname=crawler -it conda

docker network inspect crawler-network
```

Then we changed the scrapy splash settings to point to http://splash:8060, instead of http://localhost:8050